# What are the differences between platform versions of Dark Souls 1 and 2?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls, version-differences

I've heard a couple of differences between consoles for the Souls games particularly Dark Souls 1 and 2...

I was wondering if anyone knows all of the differences so that I can make a decision on which platform I'd most enjoy the game as I have just gotten a brand new PC with huge specs. although I have PS3 and Xbox 360 I only have the Souls collection for the PS Platform.

So yeah what are the most noticeable differences in gameplay cross-platform, for the souls games?

**[Edit]**

To clear up confusion I am looking for differences in the game set up such as differences in Drop rates, Amounts of souls gained from kills, and durability of equipment etc...

Comment: May want to elaborate the question a little bit. Are you asking about gameplay differences or performance?

Comment: I am not being condescending when I say this so please don't take offence but it does say differences in gameplay in the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dark souls 1: PC requires lots of community fixes for the game to play well. When they are installed, game quality is similar. It comes with the DLC that the console versions do not. You always here about 'lots of hackers' but outside of the community PvP areas, I have never run into one

Dark souls 2: Console/PC versions are mostly identical. The PC version is still best played with a controller, although there have been a lot of improvements to the mouse+keyboard support. The small differences seem to be related to the increased framerate available for the PC (60 fps for PC when consoles are locked at 30). Weapon durability degradation and some enemy animations are reportedly quicker because they are tied to the frame rate. Again, there are more reports of hackers on the PC version, but I have not run into anyone who was obviously cheatering (aside from a few binoboosters). New patches seem to be coming to both PC and consoles at about the same rate (maybe 1 or 2 week difference between platforms) and contain the same fixes.

Note: mention of hacker experience is my personal experience. I have at least 100 hours into both the PC and console versions of Dark Souls 1 (likely closer to 200 hours each), and about 100 hours on the PC version of Dark Souls 2. I am a regular PvP player.

Comment: My experience is the same with the hackers. I have plenty of hours in the souls series and have seen very few (no?) hackers, but plenty of binoboosters and parrywalkers (glitchers) in DSII.

Answer (score 0):

First off: Not PS4. Not saying that because I am an Xbox guy, but because Dark Souls 2 isn't available on that console.

PC has it's ups and downs, (as does every platform). Pros are the quality of the framerate, cons are the shear amount of hackers. (Definitely want to play offline in DkS 1).

Xbox (and Xbox One) is fine. Nothing special, but nothing bad. Pros and Cons are the same thing: the community. It's the Xbox community.

PS3 would actually probably be your best bet, good quality framerates, and a much better community. However you can get the occasional hacker, though nowhere near as many as on PC

Comment: This provides some insight but I am really looking for the differences in the game set up itself such as I heard that the weapon degradation is quicker on PC generally than others its stuff like that I am really interested in here.

Comment: Yes. Definitely. However the new mechanic is that whenever you rest at a bonfire, your weapon repairs fully, but if it breaks completely, then you have to go to a blacksmith...

Comment: Yeah I noticed this instantly when I started DS2. Its interesting, I think its a better, more realistic method of repairing weapons and it makes you more conscious of your weapon usage... its more strategic than just hack and slash your way through.

Comment: There are some other mechanics but IMO I think you're better off discovering them for yourself :) new rings, new covenants, new PvP mechanics...

Comment: See I would look to know these before I make a purchase as I am quite happy with my PS3 version just need an insight into what I'm missing on other platforms :P

Comment: Gameplay-wise: nothing. It is exactly the same game on all platforms. The defining difference is the video quality. PC > PlayStation > Xbox

Comment: First off, nobody mentioned Xbox One or PS4 anywhere in the original question. The game is only on Xbox 360 of all the Xbox platforms, so I have no idea what you are talking about with `Xbox One`. And also, because multiplayer is free on PS3 the community tends to be less mature, they solved that issue with the PS4 though ;)

Answer (score -2):

I suggest buying it for the pc. If the specs are good enough you will see beautiful graphics.

I do suggest using the Xbox 360 controller with it.

I don't realy know what you mean with difference in gameplay cross-platform, but if you mean: How does the game look?, It looks awsome on all three of them (PC, Xbox and PS). But offcourse you see a beter result on the PC.

1 last think, don;t sit near the console/pc you will play, you will die.... allot, so changes are that you will break something (most likely the controller :) )

Comment: I know the first game inside out I know the difficulty of the games its little changes in stuff like durability, drop rates, AI and so on

Answer (score -2):

Pc: if you dont mind adding a few mods then this is the best choice (assuming you have a corded xbox 360 controller/wireless receiver or a ps3 controller.)

If any of these urks you, or makes you feel otherwise I would get it on console (assuming you dont mind some haaaardcore framedrops in some areas :P

Dark souls 2 is better on pc hands down. Looks much better and plays at 60fps

Comment: Its not about the performance of the game as siad in other answer responses